# Delete code when sync github source code to S3 with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to use code pipeline in AWS CDK to automatically deploy code from GitHub source to S3 bucket. The code is as follows:

```
import * as codepipeline from '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline';
import * as codepipeline_actions from '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions';
import * as s3 from '@aws-cdk/aws-s3';
import { Construct, Stack, StackProps } from '@aws-cdk/core';

export class S3PipelineStack extends Stack {

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps = {}) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const dagsBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'my-bucket', `test-bucket`);

    const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'my-s3-pipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'MyS3Pipeline',
    });

    const sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();

    const sourceAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction({
      actionName: 'Source',
      owner: '***',
      repo: '***',
      connectionArn: 'arn:aws:***',
      output: sourceOutput,
      branch: 'master',
    });

    const deployAction = new codepipeline_actions.S3DeployAction({
      actionName: 'S3Deploy',
      bucket: dagsBucket,
      input: sourceOutput,
    });

    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: 'Source',
      actions: [sourceAction],
    });

    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: 'Deploy',
      actions: [deployAction],
    });
  }
}
```

This code works but the only problem is the S3 bucket can only add or change the code when source change in GitHub but cannot delete any code when anything deleted from source.

And I found a note in aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-s3deploy.html) that said:
[image]

Another possible solution is from [`s3deploy.BucketDeployment`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-deployment-readme.html) but again it doesn't support connecting source from git but only can pass a source from local or another S3 bucket.

So does anybody know how to sync the GitHub and S3 bucket with `add`/`change`/`delete` from source in the right way?

Comment: What is your use case for having code in an s3 bucket? CodeStar can use your github as a source for pretty much anything you'd need code for, and s3 webpages are Static.  If you can't use CodeStar for some reason (it even works with Github Enterprise servers now) then you can just load your code into CodeCommit for the same functionality.

Otherwise, you'll have to make a custom lambda that uses the github api to determine what changed/deleted and do so accordingly in your s3 bucket.

Comment: @lynkfox, My use case is using the S3 bucket for aws managed apache airflow. So the whole airflow including the S3 bucket need to be automated by aws CDK. I just wonder if there is a CDK API available to do this

Comment: Allright - I think your best solution would be to make use of the SDK to do what you want. That is one of the beautiful things about CDK - if you have deploy time things that you need to do, you can build them into the stacks using the SDK of your language of choice - for instance, I have a bit of code to find the latest version of a layer from another stack and import that rather than create an identical layer in a somewhat unrelated stack. Since my cdk is in python, i use boto3 commands to find the layer version.